# php glob function is not working when directory is created using mkdir function

Tags: php

I am creating folders using php. When I use php's `glob` function on a directory it does not return anything. If I create a folder manually in same directory then `glob` works fine.

Code:

```
$uploaded_files_location = "../propertyImages/".$LastId."/";
echo $uploaded_files_location;
  if (file_exists($uploaded_files_location))
   {
} 
else 
{
    mkdir($uploaded_files_location);
}
```

To get files from directory I am using this:

Code:

```
$dir = "../propertyImages/".$id."";
$files = glob("$dir/*.*");
print_r($files);
```

Comment: and folder those created with php am not even able to delete or rename those folder from my computer

Comment: Are you sure that your directory actually contains something ?

Comment: yes i have images on that folder

Comment: could you add echo with all your variables and provide the values?

Comment: @rullof i am using print_r function to echo all files in that directory..

Comment: Are you running php as different user other than what you use to login? Sound like permission issues maybe

Comment: Make sure the relative path is valid from within the execution context. Maybe change to `$dir = __DIR__"/../propertyImages/".$id`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried change chmod of folder and files in it?

Try this:

```
mkdir($uploaded_files_location, 0777);
```